# Assembler Category Listing Pages in Endeca Assembler

Tags: atg, endeca, endeca-workbench

I am working on the Assembler Category Listing Pages and  gave the following query:

http://localhost:7003/rest/model/syed/search/impl/SearchRestService/catalogDisplay?includePath=/services/guidedsearch&N=0&Ne=1515682953

It is returning all the Root Level categories, however I also need to return the Sub Level Categories. How to achieve it using Assembler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get a second level of categories (dim values) out of the box. You will need to build a custom handler for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `Ne=<id#1>+<id#2>+<id#3>`

Refer to *Dimensions and dimension values* section of [Endeca Concepts Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28906_01/Common.622/pdf/EndecaConceptsGuide.pdf) for more information.